# Hiding page to a specific user

Tags: php, html, laravel

I recently received a request to hide a certain page from a certain type of user. for this I created a structure called "masters" VARCHAR, NULL, inside the "users" table. I want to put "1" in the user that I want him to see the page and "0" for those who can't see it. What would be the best suggestion?

```
  <li>
    <a href="masters">
      <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
      <p>Materials</p>
    </a>
  </li>



Route::get('/masters', function () {
    return view('masters');
});
```

Comment: do you want to hide the whole page or do you want to hide part of the page?

Comment: laravel policy will solve this kind of problem https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Gates, in your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('masters', function ($user) {
        return $user->masters == "1";
    });
}
```

and then your routes will be. This will hide the whole page.

```php
Route::get('/masters', function () {
    return view('masters');
})->middleware('can:masters');
```

if you want to hide part of the page

```php
@can('masters')
    <!-- The Current User Can see this part -->
@endcan
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are using Laravel, for now, I m using another framework so I forget a little bit the syntax so for that, you need to define your middleware you see in your registration form there is defined a middleware that restricts the access to your web application so tape middleware and watch a course about it with that notion you can restrict access and put for guest and specific user whatever you want to display.

Comment: Very well thought out, I am trying to create middleware, it just isn't working so I thought about posting here, but I thank and appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you like to hide an HTML block inside Blade template? You can use a conditional in blade to check user, something like this:

```
@if (Auth::user()->masters) 
  <li>
    <a href="masters">
      <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
      <p>Materials</p>
    </a>
  </li>
@endif
```

Comment: maybe hiding is complicated, but just blocking those with "0" in the structure, if I can show an alert "only masters can see" it would be enough.

Comment: Something like this:

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){ 
    Route::get('/masters', function () {
      if (\Auth::user()->masters) {
          return view('masters');
      } else {
          return view('only-masters-view');
      }
    });
});`